# Are there any existing model weights for buildings segmentation from aerial images?

Tags: deep-learning, image-classification

I'd like to test some deep learning techniques to extract buildings footprint from aerial imagery. I've found many references related to this problem ([here](https://deepsense.ai/satellite-images-semantic-segmentation-with-deep-learning/), [or here](https://journal.baygeo.org/deep-learning-aerial-imagery)), but only providing the model architecture and the process of learning.

I don't have easy access to hardware material in order to train a model. So I was looking for existing model weights (hdf5 or onnx files from state-of-the-art works) or pre-packaged script I could directly use as-is, just to make tests.

Do you know any repository or library with such model weights provided ?

I don't need to classify objects on the image, but only identify buildings (binary classification).

Answer (score 0):

You can run .py and .ipynb if you have no hardware access via Google collab. That way allows you to train majority of NNs posted on github.

Also I found this pretrained network with utils for importing the NN as .ONNX: https://github.com/cuicaihao/aerial-image-segmentation/
So I run the `export_onnx.py` in Collab with adding `opset_version=11` to `torch.onnx.export` args and got the .ONNX for the segmentation network.